# How much room does a fridge coil need to dissipate heat?

Tags: heating, kitchens, refrigerator

I want to put a small bar fridge in the (rather large) kitchen cupboard under my sink to ultimately be used as a [kegerator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kegerator).

The fridge will be a custom free-standing insulated box (similar to [this one](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f51/homemade-portable-2-5-gallon-keg-cooler-250426/)) which uses the thermostat, compressor, cooling element, and rear coils from a standard 4ft<sup>3</sup> bar fridge.  I measured the cupboard to be 28ft<sup>3</sup>.  The cupboard is not ventilated, but isn't sealed either.  It's opened pretty often, and the two big sinks might help conduct heat out of there.

What do you think? Will heat dissipation be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure whether your installation will work, but heat dissipation could be a problem. The fridge innards you plan to use were meant for a refrigerator that has free air exchange with the rest of the house. Sealing it up under a counter with no free air movement will hinder its performance. Refrigerators that are built for under-counter installation have the coils mounted on the bottom (with a grate in front of the coils) for this reason. You could try mounting the coils on the side or bottom of the cold box, closer to the open air of the kitchen, with a vent panel as Steven suggests.

Answer (score 0):

How this will perform will depend a lot on the temperature of the room it is in.   As long as the room temp doesn't get too high in the summer time it should do alright.

If it where me, I would try to find a way to integrate some ventilation into the cabinet to allow air to circulate.   Perhaps a vent in the kick plate along with one in the side of the cabinet?